# AcceptCase another user to current login user

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button, webservices, detail-page

Case is not Accepting from Accept case Detail page button(javascript button).

Error Message :

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was
>   encountered:
>
> {faultcode:'soapenv:Client',faultstring:'No operation available for
>   request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/package/acceptCaseCont}
>   changeOwner,please check the wsdl for the service.',}

I have a button on case detail page "**Accept Case**" its a Detail Page Button. Behavior is **Execute JavaScript** and onClick JavaScript is

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 

var cObj = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
cObj.id = '{!Case.Id}'; 
var id = sforce.apex.execute("acceptCaseCont","changeOwner", 
{caseIn: cObj}); 
location.reload();
```

Class Code

```
global class acceptCaseCont{   
    webService static Id changeOwner(Case caseIn) {
        Case cs = [select id, OwnerId from Case where Id = :caseIn.Id];
        cs.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        update cs;
        return cs.id;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It should be easier by just passing the case Id as a String parameter.

Comment: Otherwise, If your org is under a namespace, include namespace in execute call. I would also check if user is having appropriate permission for class or to update Case record.

Comment: @MartinLezer I tried and pass case id but it's not working same error message showing.

Comment: @RahulSharma user have already read write permission

Comment: On Salesforce, when you read the apex class file, you have a "Security" tab. Did you check that the user profile is listed as Enabled profiles?

Comment: yes i have checked and its enabled

Comment: Did you try to make an `alert('{!Case.Id}');` to check if the id is returned?

Comment: @MartinLezer yes id is returned showing in alert.

Comment: only minor mistake was there. i forget to add namespace it's very silly mistake. mine org namespace is DreamSalesforce

  sforce.apex.execute("DreamSalesforce.acceptCaseCont","changeOwner", 
{caseIn: cObj});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace added and code will work.

```
         {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
         {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 

       var cObj = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
       cObj.id = '{!Case.Id}'; 
       var id = sforce.apex.execute("DreamSalesforce.acceptCaseCont","changeOwner", 
      {caseIn: cObj}); 
        location.reload();
```